# Undefined Reference C++ Queue Template Handling Strings

Tags: c++, templates, queue

I am working on homework where I have to write a template and then implement the template into a driver.  Unfortunately, I'm receiving an error when compiling.  I'm just beginning to learn the more complex aspects of C++, and I have no idea how to resolve this problem.

/tmp/ccdvvLpF.o:main.cpp:    (.text$_ZN11LinkedQueueISsE7enqueueERKSs[LinkedQueue, std::allocator > >::enqueue(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)]+0x4a): undefined reference to `LinkedQueue<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::number'
/tmp/ccdvvLpF.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN11LinkedQueueISsE7enqueueERKSs[LinkedQueue<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::enqueue(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x66): undefined reference to`LinkedQueue, std::allocator > >::number'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdvvLpF.o: bad reloc address 0x66 in section `.text$_ZN11LinkedQueueISsE7enqueueERKSs[LinkedQueue, std::allocator > >::enqueue(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)]'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks.

Comment: The homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: Your header guard ends prematurely. Is that intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static int number` is never defined. Add the following definition outside of your class.

```
template <class T> int LinkedQueue<T>::number = 0;
```

`static` members are *special*, `static int number` inside the class is only a declaration and not a definition. The reason for this is because headers are usually included in *multiple* translation units, so C++ forces you to define them outside of the class usually in a cpp file so that you do not get multiple definition errors.